# Feature installation error wmqjmsclient-1.1

Tags: jms, open-liberty

**Feature installation error:**

Trying to install the JMS-MQ by enabling this **wmqjmsclient-1.1** or **wmqjmsclient-2.0** feature as per documentation. Both versions are giving the same error, please let me know how can I install/enable this feature.

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.openliberty.tools:liberty-maven-plugin:3.3.4:run (default-cli) on project CC: CWWKF1299E: The following features could not be obtained: wmqjmsclient-1.1. Ensure that the features are valid for Open Liberty. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1):

`wmqJmsClient` isn't available in Open Liberty, only WebSphere Liberty. To use MQ with Open Liberty, you can create a `resourceAdapter` element like in this example (https://github.com/epomatti/openliberty-jms-mq-example/blob/47171bec7ef8a1e701ae363293a6cfd6a9bd5b32/liberty/server.xml#L12)

```
<resourceAdapter id="wmqjmsra"
    location="${server.config.dir}/wmq.jmsra.rar" />
```

Make sure you choose an id other than `wmqJms` like the example, as there can be issues. You'll use that name to specify the properties, like that same example file:

```
<jmsQueue id="jms/queue1" jndiName="jms/queue1">
    <properties.wmqjmsra baseQueueManagerName="QM1"
        baseQueueName="DEV.QUEUE.1" />
</jmsQueue>
```

Make sure to enable the `jms-2.0` feature itself if you don't have any other features pulling it in.